# Creating a submenu in context menu from overridden getActions in Java JHotDraw

Tags: java, swing, contextmenu

I am overriding the `getActions` method in the Java based framework [`JHotDraw`](http://www.jhotdraw.org/), an open source project hosted [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jhotdraw/). The method `getActions` creates a right click context menu on `Figure` in the `Drawingview`. I can correctly add addidtional context menu options using the code below. I need to know how to add a sub menu to the context menu.

```
@Override
public Collection<Action> getActions(Point2D.Double p) {
  Collection<Action> popupMenu = new ArrayList<Action>();
  popupMenu.add(new AbstractAction("add Context Option 1") {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
      preformThisMethod("params");
    }
  });
  popupMenu.add(new AbstractAction("add Context Option 2") {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
      preformThisMethod("params");
    }
  });
  // How to add a sub menu to the context menu?
  return popupMenu;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the [usual approach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)?

Comment: I wish I could use the `JPopupMenu` aproach. I have to use the framework approaches {Homework Requirement}. I'm in a software engineering class with loose requirements about HOW we achieve functionality, so long as we utilize the JHotDraw framework. This means I need to override certain methods, like `getActions`. I'm not even sure if it is possible to create a submenu using this `Action` collection approach of the JHotDraw framework, it just would be an exceedingly convenient and intuitive way to implement the desired functionality.

Comment: After many hours of struggling, I determined that a submenu isn't possible given the framework's structure handling context menus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding submenus is supported.

The class `org.jhotdraw.gui.JPopupButton` extends `JButton` to provide the popup menus used throughout the framework. The method `add(javax.swing.JMenu submenu)` may be used to construct hierarchical submenus. For example, `org.jhotdraw.samples.draw.DrawingPanel` adds a `Zoom` submenu to the rightmost popup menu in `creationToolbar`, along with other miscellaneous editing actions. The method `createFontButton()` in `org.jhotdraw.draw.action.ButtonFactory` is another example used to `addFontButtonsTo()` the editor.

In contrast, right-clicking on the `org.jhotdraw.draw.DefaultDrawingView` is handled by an instance of `javax.swing.JPopupMenu` in `org.jhotdraw.draw.DelegationSelectionTool`, as shown in `org.jhotdraw.samples.mini.EditorSample`. In particular, the `AbstractAction` property `Actions.SUBMENU_KEY` identifies a submenu name. Set `DEBUG = true` to see the effect. None are presently defined.