# Passing JMenuItem to Controller Class

Tags: java, sql, swing, oop, design-patterns

I Have 3 sets of `JMenuItem` on a View class of the MVC framework. I want to refer to them in the controll class `EventController`. Can someone show me this is achieved? Below is the event Controller. Class EventView consists of `JMenuItem` addEvent, editEvent, deleteEvent, how do I do the listeners for them in the Controller class. Can someone demonstrate using a sample code on top of my Controller class?

```
public class EventController implements ActionLister {
private EventModel model;
private EventView view;
private ActionListener actionListener;


public EventController(EventModel model, EventView view){
    this.model = model;
    this.view = view;
}
```

Second question, I can only update a `JTable` from the `View` class itself, so

```
public void updateEventTable() {
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT date as 'Date',eventName as 'Name', time as 'Time' FROM Event";
         pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
         rs = pst.executeQuery();
         tableEvent.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
         tableEvent.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(80);
         tableEvent.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(170);
         tableEvent.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(110);  
    }
    catch (Exception e ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close(); pst.close();conn.close();;
        } catch(SQLException e){}
    }
}
```

This is bad practice having codes in View Class, Should ideally be in Model, but how to do this can you show me. The concepts is new to me and want to learn. Because of `JTable` I find it very difficult

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let your model export instances of [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) that can be added to menus and buttons as needed. Because database access is inherently asynchronous, let each such action use a [worker thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to query the database in the background while updating the table mode on the EDT. See also [*A Swing Architecture Overview*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html) concerning the relationship between Swing components and models.

Addendum: *Can you show me a code sample?*

- [`FileMenu`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513) is a very basic example of using `Action` to encapsulate functionality.
- The example cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11944233/230513) uses `Action` more extensively in a `JToolBar`.
- [`JHotDraw`](http://www.jhotdraw.org/), cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13997870/230513), is a very complex example that changes the available `Action` instances based on context, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13312223/230513).
- This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513) offers a general examination of MVC in Swing.

Comment: How does the controller come in this as a gateway fro the model and view to communication. can you show me a code sample? I am concerned with controller class retrieving the address of the JMenuItems, like a reference to it so that the action is performed in controller class and not View Class